# C# WPF i can't enter foreach loop!

Tags: c#, wpf

I am creating an application with C# WPF:

I have have dynamically generated treeview

In that treeview I have a `TreeViewItem` called BoekenLijst.

There I generate dynamic `TreeViewItem`s like "the hobbit". The book content, like "the hobbit", I store in the `Content` property of a `Checkbox`.

So the treeview will look like this:

Treeview>
     TreeViewItem(BoekenLijst)>
                      The Hobbit
                        Code Complete

I want to put the checked `TreeViewItem`s in a `ListBox` so I did the following:

```
 private List<TreeViewItem> GetAllItemContainers(TreeViewItem itemsControl)
    {
        List<TreeViewItem> allItems = new List<TreeViewItem>();
        for (int i = 0; i < itemsControl.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            // try to get the item Container  
            TreeViewItem childItemContainer = itemsControl.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(i) as TreeViewItem;
            // the item container maybe null if it is still not generated from the runtime  
            if (childItemContainer != null)
            {
                allItems.Add(childItemContainer);
                List<TreeViewItem> childItems = GetAllItemContainers(childItemContainer);


                foreach (TreeViewItem childItem in childItems)
                {
                    CheckBox checkBoxTemp = childItem.Header as CheckBox;

                    if (checkBoxTemp != null)
                        optieListBox.Items.Add(checkBoxTemp.Content);

                    allItems.Add(childItem);
                }
            }
        }
        return allItems;
    }
```

The problem is, it won't go into:  foreach (TreeViewItem childItem in childItems)

Can someone help me out?

Comment: Is it skipping the loop? Because that means `childItems` is empty. Put a breakpoint just before the loop and check the contents of childItems.

Comment: @bubye, this is the sort of bug that you need to find yourself.  Ask for help only after you've tried to trace through the problem and failed.  Then include info on what you've tried.

Comment: ChildItems Count = 0, I've tried to do certain things, and this is the problem i can't get out @Stephen Chung

Comment: Well then there you go. How can it loop over the children if there are none?

Comment: But the treeview got items in it why doesn't it add it to childitems :S

Comment: Is childItemContainer null?  Are you sure `itemsControl.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(i)` is not returning null?

Comment: Ok so i deleted the line  List<TreeViewItem> childItems = GetAllItemContainers(childItemContainer);
Because i am already in the right TreeviewItem.
Now i got this error at optieListBox.Items.Add(checkBoxTemp.Content); Element already has a logical parent. It must be detached from the old parent before it is attached to a new one.

Comment: @bubye Once you add an element somewhere in your hierarchy it has to stay there, you can't go moving elements around like with HTML DOM.

Comment: @Jonas Van der Aa it has to stay there but i need to create a copy of it in another listbox

Comment: @bubye this is bad practice, you should use [data binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750612.aspx) and [data templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521.aspx)

Comment: checkBoxTemp.Content = childItemContainer.Header as CheckBox; it says Specified element is already the logical child of another element. Disconnect it first.

Comment: @bubye you are not moving the actual `CheckBox` but you are referring to it while it is still a child of another element. WPF does not allow this.

Comment: Ok! So how do i move the actual checkbox in to a new one ???

Comment: You don't, see my earlier comment about data binding and data templates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried running it through the Visual Studio debugger?  If you insert the break point where the error is getting thrown, then you should be able to get a stack trace of what's going on, and if it's anything like the Eclipse debugger (I've not used VS in a while) you should be able to click on any variable in the code or hold the mouse over it, and it will display the current value of that variable in memory.

But I echo what the others say, try and figure out for yourself, take your time, and work through it step by step.  I had to learn that myself, and I still get it wrong as I always forget to use the debugger...ask my team leader if you don't believe me :-)

Welshboy